# vbscript to preserve access denial file while in remove process

Tags: vbscript, access-denied

I have a problem while I try to remove some folder/file in one specify folder on a server with a limit time, and some of folder/file can't remove and preserve some folder/file while they are in access denial status, can vbs do it?

Comment: If any process has a lock on a folder or file you can't move, rename or delete it. This comes from windows, no love here like linux :)

Comment: Many thx your comment, however, I want to skip this access denial file/folder to continue process the next remove action, can VBscrpit do it?

Comment: @YvesR The difference is merely in the [default behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking). If a process chooses to lock a file, access to the file will be denied for other processes, regardless of the operating system.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers On a linux system you can delete or modify a folder or a file, even when it is open. At least this is default on most linux systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer your question in your comment here, because more space to write :)

If you want to access and this fails then VBscript raise an error.
Your script stop working. Solution here is to implement an error handling.
So what you can do is to move that part into a sub routine or function and activate `On Error Resume Next` like this:

```
Sub DeleteFolder(p_sFolder)
  Err.Clear
  On Error Resume Next

  Dim fso : Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim deletefolder : Set deletefolder = fso.GetFolder(p_sFolder)
  deletefolder.Delete(True) 
  Set fso = Nothing

  If Err.Number<>0 THen
    Wscript.Echo Err.Number
    Wscript.Echo Err.Description
    ' here you can handle with the error with additional code
  End If

End Sub
```